# stick part in a specific range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fixed

i have a container that is stick to top after a specific point.
but its not enough for me.
i have a footer in the page and when the screen is small the stick part is hiding under the footer.
i want it to stop moving down in the footer top (to stop be fixed to 0 that point but be fixed to minus number that is the substraction between them).
this is my code.
what should i add for that goal?
and when to call it?
on resize?
on ready?
etc.

thanks a lot

```
    window.onscroll = function (event) {
        fixDiv();
    };
    function fixDiv() {
        if (getBrowserHeight().width > 1284) {
            var $div = $("#Container");
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) {
                $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0' });
            }
            else {
                $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto' });
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Container").data("top", $("#Container").offset().top); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.
Don't mind to ask for help if somehting isn't clear.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var footerEl = $('footer').offset().top;
    var footerTop = (footerEl - $(window).scrollTop());
    var containerHeight = $('.container').height();
    var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
    console.log('footer', footerTop);
    $('.container').removeClass('sticky');

    if (footerTop <= containerHeight) {
      $('.container').addClass('sticky');
      $('.container').css('bottom', footerHeight);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make as few changes to your code as possible, but there's better ways to get around this ie. using classes, like in @mhx answer. Full JavaScript below (sorry, had to remove your `getBrowserHeight()` as it wasn't defined):

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
    fixDiv();
};
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#Container");
    var $footer = $("footer");

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $div.data("top") && $(window).scrollTop() < $footer.data("top") - $div.height()) {
        $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0' });
    } 
    else if ($footer.data("top") > $footer.data("top") - $div.height()) {
        $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': $footer.data("top") - $div.height() });
    }
    else {
        $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto' });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Container").data("top", $("#Container").offset().top); 
    $("footer").data("top", $("footer").offset().top); 
});
```

Besides adding a top data attribute to your footer and defining `$footer` in the start of `fixDiv()`,I've added this to your initial if statement, to make sure that the scroll position, does not exceed the top of the footer minus the height of your div.

```
&& $(window).scrollTop() < $footer.data("top") - $div.height()
```

... and I've added this else if statement, in case it does exceed the top of the footer minus the height of your div

```
else if ($footer.data("top") > $footer.data("top") - $div.height()) {
    $('#Container').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top': $footer.data("top") - $div.height() });
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ds5tptay/